# Ubuntu error Cannot mount USB drive Not Authorized

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10

I have a Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop. Until now I was able to mount any external drives (USB flash drives which have FAT, SD Cards having ext4 partitions/filesystems using USB SD Card adapters). Both of which give same error in mounting. 
But now I am facing an error in mounting external USB drive:

```
Unable to mount : Not Authorized
```

But upon connecting a USB drive to the USB port, the USB symbols are shown in the Unity Launcher bar. When when I try to open those folders from file manager by clicking on them, I get

```
Unable to mount : Not Authorized
```

Also when I try to remove them safely or eject nothing happens.

When i did `sudo fdisk -l` I see the partitions from the external device mounted.

on /dev/sdb1,2....

But I do not see same mounted partitions when i run command `df`

I have not installed/uninstalled/upgraded any package or library which might have caused this.
I have searched [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120147/cant-mount-usb-not-authorized) as well as here. As mentioned by some solutions I do not see an option like Administration->User and Groups.

```
 System->Administration->User and Groups ->Properties->User Privileges tab. You should have the "Access external storage devices automatically" option checked."
```

This is really annoying problem and I am not able to get an fix/workaround going.

**EDIT:
I just checked with a different user account on the same machine, automount of the external storage worked fine, so now starting to suspect some permission or such issues. But what where , no idea?**

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: fdisk does not show mounted partitions, it will show all of them. df shows only mounted so that discrepancy is not a problem.

Comment: @terdon - Yes I know. But when the device is removed from USB drive, fdisk does not list the sdb ones

Comment: Yes, it just sounds like you don't have permission to mount USB drives and gvfs is not set up to mount them automatically. Can you mount manually with `sudo`?

Comment: Will try mounting manually. Do i need to know how many and what type of partitions are present on a external USB / SD Card to try mounting it using mount command?

Comment: You need to know the name of at least one partition. You can get that from the output of `fdisk -l` or `dmesg | tail` after plugging the drive in. If you have a partition called `sdb1` for example, just create a directory and mount it: `mkdir foo; sudo mount /dev/sdb1 foo`.

Comment: Please show us the output of `groups` run by your normal user and by the one who can mount.

Comment: Output of groups command ad17 is the user which is facing problems in automounting the External USB drives. ad17 : ad17 adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
The other account ajit can automount drives ok.
ajit : ajit adm lpadmin admin sambashare

Comment: @terdon - It does mount manually fine , when i tried using mount command.